# executing js via cfhttp

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, listener, background-process

Im trying to execute a some JS code via a background task.

Im using a gateway which works similar to paypal, i.e. once payment details are taken a response is sent back to a listener on my server (this could be immediate or several minutes later)

Once a response is received by the listener (listener.cfm), using cfhttp im calling a file (runPixCode.cfm) which has some trigger code. 
Because runPixCode.cfm is not rendered by the browser the JS is not executing.

Also to prove whether this worked or not, im getting the JS to call another file (provethisiscalled.cfm) which write a log to a txt file.

If i put the following straight after the cfhttp call, i can see an entry in the log file. This assures me there is no issue with the JS providing its rendered by the browser.

```
<cfoutput>#cfhttp.FileContent#</cfoutput><cfabort>
```

However, doesnt work with a background task. I dont know how else to deal with this, any suggestions appreciated.

listener.cfm

```
--Does a bunch of logic--
<cfif paymentsuccessful>
    <CFHTTP URL="www.mysite.com/runPixCode.cfm" METHOD="post" timeout="12" resolveurl="true">
      <CFHTTPPARAM NAME="TrackingId" VALUE="#trackingId#" TYPE="FormField">
    </CFHTTP>
</cfif>
```

runPixCode.cfm

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
    var axel = Math.random()+""; 
    var a = axel * 1000; 
    document.write('<IFRAME SRC="http://www.mysite.com/provethisiscalled.cfm?codearea=landing&num='+ a + '?" WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 FRAMEBORDER=0></IFRAME>'); 
</SCRIPT>
<NOSCRIPT><IFRAME SRC="http://www.mysite.com/provethisiscalled.cfm?codearea=landing&num=1" WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 FRAMEBORDER=0></IFRAME> </NOSCRIPT>
```

provethisiscalled.cfm

```
<cfloop collection=#ARGUMENTS.triggerParams# item="key"> 
        <cfset docLogging = docLogging & chr(13) & "#key# = " & ARGUMENTS.triggerParams[key]> 
</cfloop>
<cffile action="append" file="c:\serverlocation\someDir\triggerlog.txt" output="#docLogging#" addnewline="YES" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing an iframe is not going to work, nor is javascript, because all of these processes are being called by applications, not by browsers.

So with that, you have to get creative. First, what are you really attempting to do?

If your purpose is to determine whether or not a file has been called or executed, use `<cflog>` or write an entry to a database.

If you are trying to pass an HTTP call from listener.cfm to runPixCode.cfm, use `<cfhttp>` instead of an iframe.

If your purpose is actually to execute JavaScript as part of this automated process (it isn't, but this is cool), you can execute JavaScript in your CF/Java server through Rhino, which is not incredibly simple, but you can get code snippets by googling. Rhino is included with ColdFusion as `js.jar`, so there are no special files to download to make it work.

Comment: thanks for your reply Nathan, the purpose is to execute JS. The reason im calling the CF file from JS is to ensure the JS is executing. I'll give Rhino a go right away :) i hope it works as i've burnt too much time on this.

Comment: Keep in mind using Rhino in CF is executing JavaScript server side. Sounds to me like you're trying to confirm that the client can execute a piece of JavaScript.